# Circuit for 3 stage lead acid battery charger controlled by microcontroller advice

Tags: charger

I designed the circuit below as a mashup of different ideas.
It is a lead acid battery charger controlled by a microcontroller. The relay allows the micro to select between the constant current circuit and the constant voltage circuit. The micro can also select between 2 constant voltages (14.6V and 13.5V). The micro can read the current and voltage being applied using the INA240 for current and a voltage divider for voltage. Each of these signals is fed into a 555 timer which generates a Pulse-Position Modulation signal, which the micro can read (the micro does not have ADC inputs). The requirement is for low cost parts (although the INA240 is not cheap). It also has a simple switchover circuit based on schottky diodes.

Would you mind looking at the design and tell me if my logic is sound?
[image: v1 of design]

Update: After reviewing Bruce's comments, all very valid, I decided to redesign the circuit. Below is v2
[image: v2 of design]

Comment: _"The requirement is for low cost parts (although **the INA240 is not cheap**)"_ - neither is the LM317, and you have 3 of them. What's your BOM cost? Why can't you use an MCU with ADC inputs?

Comment: The INA240 costs 12x the cost of the LM317. The microcontroller can't be changed.

Comment: ok, so after more research, the design has a fatal flaw. The power dissipation of the LM317's will be far too high. e.g. for the 5V regulator the power dissipation will be 
(24V-5V)*1A = 19W ! , for a TO252 package working temp of 60 degrees C, working in an ambient temp of 30 degrees C this would need a heatsink with 1.6 degrees C / W  Going to find a better solution...

Comment: Yes, I could have pointed that out - but thought it was better you found out for yourself. If you really do need 1A at 5V then consider using a DC/DC converter module (I buy them in bulk off eBay and stick them in everything). The LM317 has over-temp protection which simply throttles back the current if it gets too hot, just like popular USB charger ICs do. But you won't get 1.78A out of one. Efficient chargers use a buck-mode switching regulator with current limiting. Cheap DC/DC modules that do that are also available.

Answer (score 2):

The transistor operated by GPIO7 is wired wrong. The Emitter should go to ground and the 20k resistor should go from the Collector to the LM317 ADJ pin. You will also need a current limiting resistor from the Base to GPIO7.

LED3 in series with the optocoupler input will reduce LED and optocoupler input current to ~0.5 mA (assuming it is a red LED with voltage drop of ~1.7 V), which may not be enough to turn the relay control transistor fully on. You might be able to fix this by powering the optocoupler with 5 V instead of 3.3 V.

The NE555 voltage to 'pulse position' converters are not very linear or accurate, and will have to be calibrated individually. You might consider using an SPI or I<sup>2</sup>C ADC (eg. [ADS1115](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1114.pdf)) instead.

If the MCU supply voltage is 3.3 V then GPIO14 and GPIO15 will have to be 5 V tolerant. If not then you should put resistor dividers on the 555 outputs to drop the voltage down to 3.3 V.

Apart from those issues the circuit looks like it should work, though it might be possible to use fewer and/or cheaper parts. For example if you are able to put the current sensor resistor on the negative side of the battery then you could replace the INA240 with an op amp, and a single LM317 could be used for both voltage and current regulation (eliminating the relay etc.).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to have a look at the design. I removed the LED's and the 555 timers. Used the ADS1115 as you suggested. Moved the current sense to the low side, added a LM741 to control the voltage regulators output via PWM and changed how the constant current source is configured.

Comment: The relay now switches off the chargers output to the battery, in order to measure the battery voltage for analysis